# Get forum email notification when replay

Tags: forum

i am following a couple of forums which having difficulty keep tracking replies,
what i am looking for a method to send me an email notifications when a replay is being posted, and preferably if i can specify alert for a replay from specific user,

Thanks all,

Comment: anyone, any ideas how to get the alert done?

Answer (score 0):

- Most forum software will allow you to subscribe to threads.  (Even threads that you're not posting in.)
- You could look into a web service that detects changes to a webpage.  http://www.changedetection.com/ is one example I found via Google but I'm not sure if it's appropriate for your situation or how well it would work with forum pages since the same thread could change hundreds of times.
- Besides those options, a custom screen scraper/crawler could work but that seems like a lot of work.